# Triggering Promise.fulfill on an outer-scope event

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, dom-events

I'm using a sound player called `IonSound.js` which can be found here. http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html

According to the documentation, I can listen for `sound.ended` event like so:

```
ion.sound({
    sounds: [
        {name: "door_bump"},
        {name: "water_droplet_2"},
        {name: "water_droplet_3"}
    ],
    ended_callback: function (sound) {
        // sound ended
        game.sound.soundEnded(sound);
    }
});
```

I made a very basic wrapper on top of this.

```
class Sound
{
    constructor(ion) {
        this.ion = ion;
        this.promises = {};
    }

    play(sound) {
        if (game.settings.muted === false) {
            this.ion.sound.play(sound);
        }

        this.promises[sound] = new Promise((accept, reject) => {

        });

        return this.promises[sound];
    }

    soundEnded(sound) {
        if (this.events.hasOwnProperty(sound.name) === true) {
            Promise.resolve(this.promises[sound.name])
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, when I execute the following code:

```
game.sound.play("level-up");
```

`ended_callback` triggers. Then it calls `sound.soundEnded`.

The problem is, it becomes a mess like so. What I want to do instead is promisifying my Sound class so I can use it like so:

```
game.sound.play("level-up").then(() => {
    console.log("Sound is over.");
});
```

In order to do it, this piece of code has to `fulfill()` my Promise that I kept on `this.promises` hash.

```
Promise.resolve(this.promises[sound.name]);
```

but it doesn't have any methods to trigger fulfill like this:

```
this.promises[sound.name].fulfill();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping an array of promises in `this.promises`, keep an array of promise accept/reject-callbacks in `this.promiseFulfil`. That way you have a handle to fulfil the promise.

Here is how your class could look:

```
class Sound
{
    constructor(ion) {
        this.ion = ion;
        this.promiseFulfil = {};
    }

    play(sound) {
        if (game.settings.muted === false) {
            this.ion.sound.play(sound);
        }

        // Just return the promise without storing it.    
        return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
            // keep track of which function to call to fulfil promise:
            this.promiseFulfil[sound] = { accept, reject };
        });
    }

    soundEnded(sound) {
        if (this.promiseFulfil[sound]) {
            // call the appropriate promise-callback:
            this.promiseFulfil[sound].accept();
            // optionally clear this entry:
            this.promiseFulfil[sound] = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're amazing. God bless your doge!